# Open .lbl file, write fields and print it

Tags: c#, printing, label

I have a productlabel (`.lbl` file crated with NiceLabel).

Using Wingforms (c#)  I want to open this label file and get the fields so I can assign data (from my database) to them and then save the label.
So in the end, I have a label with values that I can print.

Is a way t do this?

**Edit:** If possible, it would be awesome to also show the finished label in the form, to see if all values are in correct place.

Comment: Have a look at this,maybe could lead you in the right direction [link](http://www.primozic.net/nl/how-can-i-programmatically-get-a-list-of-variables-from-nicelabel/)

Comment: Hi,
thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.